# A company wide dropbox like system on top of Amazon S3

Tags: sync, dropbox, amazon-s3

Is there a system that will provide dropbox like features on top of Amazon s3?

It would be used company wide, mostly for documents, recordings, etc...
Some users work on Microsoft Windows, others on MacOS and all of them have got either an iPhone or a WP7 + an iPad.

We currently have a server where all the data is stored, we'd sync this back to Amazon S3, but then we need a way for the employers to access those files from anywhere without having to really think about it... should be transparent and we need a way to protect access to folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Jungle Disk Workgroup Edition**](https://www.jungledisk.com/business/workgroup/features/) fits your requirements.  There's even an [iPhone/iPad app](https://www.jungledisk.com/iphone_app_backup_share_files_manage_data_view_documents/default.aspx).

Comment: Problem is these guys ask a monthly fee in addition to the amazon fee. And we already have our own account with amazon

Comment: @TimothyP: It's only $4 per user and you can add your own AWS account. You do not have to use the one provided through JungleDisk.  You'll just lose the initial free 10GB of storage space that they offer.

Comment: Ah ok that makes more sense then